# Rails assets not cached in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, asset-pipeline

My rails app is in production mode and assets are compiled and i can see it in /public/assets/

In my layouts i use something like that :

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%=> javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

my javascript use the //require directive,
my css is in "css.scss" ans i use the @import sass directive to load css.scss files.

The assets are well compiled.

- **When i use chrome**, my css and js file are cached :
  application-***********.js and css are loaded one time then it is well cached in chrome. **I can navigate quickly between my pages** ...
- **When i use firefox**, each time it download the js and css concatenated files ... **browing is slow** ....

Have any idea about this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: In the web inspector settings you can disable caching when the inspector is open. Perhaps this is the case here?

Comment: The behavior is the same with or without webinspector opened, and when i look for network performance, i am using firebug ...
And there was not "disable cache" in inspector settings :/

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** : I don't know why but from the moment i start firebug, my application.js and css are each time reloaded (cache miss).

But if i restart firefox and i browse my website without launching at least one time firebug, everything goes well and i can naviguate "quickly" because the browser cache works !!!

Strange, but solved.